# PopMenu dropDown onChanged not changing current value on View

Tags: flutter

I have this Pop up menu in appBar. 
It has Drop widget that holds language value. When changing other language it updates value, but not changing in popup menu. If I close and open popup it shows last changed value.

Anything wrong in this code?.

```
class ProfilePopup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePopupState createState() => _ProfilePopupState();
}

class _ProfilePopupState extends State<ProfilePopup> {
  //_ProfilePopupState();

  String _dropdownValue = 'English';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build profilepopup');
    return _offsetPopup(context);
  }

  Widget _offsetPopup(BuildContext context) => PopupMenuButton<int>(
        //color: Theme.of(context).,
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _dropdownValue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.language),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                  print(_dropdownValue);
                },
                items: <String>[
                  'English',
                  'Japan',
                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 2,
            child: Text(
              "Select Language: $_dropdownValue",
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        offset: Offset(0, 100),
      );
}
```

Any suggestion will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `StatefulBuilder` and `StreamBuidler` 
code snippet

```
PopupMenuItem(
            value: 1,
            child: Container(child: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _dropdownValue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.language),
...             
PopupMenuItem(
              value: 2,
              child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                  stream: _events.stream,
                  initialData: _dropdownValue,
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                    return Text(
                      "Select Language: ${snapshot.data}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    );
                  }))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePopup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePopupState createState() => _ProfilePopupState();
}

class _ProfilePopupState extends State<ProfilePopup> {
  //_ProfilePopupState();

  String _dropdownValue = 'English';
  StreamController<String> _events;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _events = new StreamController<String>();
    _events.add(_dropdownValue);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build profilepopup');
    return _offsetPopup(context);
  }

  Widget _offsetPopup(BuildContext context) => PopupMenuButton<int>(
        //color: Theme.of(context).,
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 1,
            child: Container(child: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _dropdownValue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.language),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                  _events.add(_dropdownValue);
                  print(_dropdownValue);
                },
                items: <String>[
                  'English',
                  'Japan',
                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            })),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
              value: 2,
              child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                  stream: _events.stream,
                  initialData: _dropdownValue,
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                    return Text(
                      "Select Language: ${snapshot.data}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    );
                  })),
        ],
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        offset: Offset(0, 100),
      );
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          ProfilePopup(),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```